# Selecting previous anchor tag and adding a class to it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, children, css-selectors

Basically I've got two anchor tags separated by a div.

```
<a class="foo"></a>

<div class="count">0</a>

<a class="bar"></a>
```

and I'm doing something like this:

```
       var addClass = $(this).parent().children('a:first-child').addClass('new');
```

It will then add it to the first anchor tag like so:

```
<a class="foo new"></a>
```

I know using the nth:child selector is pretty expensive, so I was wondering if there was an easier way to select that previous anchor node, (while ignoring the second one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably combine [`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) with [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) (or [`eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq), since `first` just calls `eq(0)` — but I find `first` more readable):

```
$(this).prevAll("a").first().addClass("new");
// or
$(this).prevAll("a").eq(0).addClass("new");
```

`prevAll` returns all of the element's preceding siblings, in order starting with the closest sibling, and of course `first` / `eq(0)` reduces the set to the first element.

You might be tempted to use the `:first` selector with `prevAll` to avoid building up an unnecessary list of siblings, but [to my surprise it works better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933236/efficient-concise-way-to-find-next-matching-sibling) to use `first` after-the-fact.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could do this

```
$(this).parent().children('a:eq(0)').addClass('new');
```

[Learn more about :eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector)

Alternatively, if there are no elements between the `<a>` and the `<div>`, you could do

```
$(this).prev('a');
```

[Learn more about .prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Comment: `prev('a')` will always return an empty set with the markup he's quoted; I know you said "if there are no elements between" but the point is there *are*.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to :eq(), but T.J.'s works nicely and a little more elegant (not your fault, it's the nature of jQuery).

Comment: @bob_cobb: Yes, it can be very useful -- but beware that here, it has the same issues as `:first` (the selector), see the question I linked from my answer for more on that (I found it very surprising that I was better off using `.first` [the function] after-the-fact rather than `:first` the selector [`:first` = `:eq(0)`]).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for clarification. `prevAll` seems like the best way to go.  Thanks for your other link, too :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(this).siblings('a').eq(0).addClass(0);
```

Actually, if your structure is as simple as in your example, you can just do a simple:

```
$(this).prev().addClass(0);
```

jQuery's [traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) methods give you lots of ways to get to any given destination.