# jQuery how to find a non-adjacent sibling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="test">Click Me</div>
<div class="something">hello</div>
<div class="yes">yes!</div>
<div class="taco">stackoverflow</div>
<div class="super">Whatever</div>
```

How would I use jQuery to click on `$('div.test')` and change the HTML of `$('div.super')` using a single selector?

I used to think that I would have to do this:

```
$('div.test').click(function(){
  $(this).next().next().next().next().html("hello world!");
});
```

But the `next()` documentation says it can take a selector, like this:

```
.next([selector])
```

So I thought maybe I could just do this:

```
$('div.test').click(function(){
  $(this).next('.super').html("hello world!");
});
```

But that doesn't seem to find anything. What am I doing wrong. Am I misunderstanding the usage of the selector in the `next()` method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient, concise way to find next matching sibling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933236/efficient-concise-way-to-find-next-matching-sibling)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `.next('.super')` to `.siblings('.super')`.

The [`next` method](http://api.jquery.com/next/), when given a selector, will match the very next sibling if it matches the selector. It doesn't find the next sibling matching the selector.

The [`siblings` method](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) will find all siblings that match the selector passed to it.

Answer (score 3):

you're looking for [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and possibly [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('div.test').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings('.super').html("hello world!");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X36c8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use the siblings function.

```
$('div.test').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings(".super").html("hello world!");
});
```