# Get Next Element that Matches Selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, I can use `x.next()` to get the next element only if it matches my selector. I can use `x.nextAll()` to get all next siblings that match my selector. And I can use `x.nextUntil()` to get all next siblings *until* one matches my selector.

But how can I get the next element that matches my selector?

Comment: do you mean like in here:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933236/efficient-concise-way-to-find-next-matching-sibling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine both:

```
var matchElement = $('elem').nextUntil('matchSelector').next();
```

or

```
var matchElement = $('elem').nextAll('matchSelector:first'); //$('elem').nextAll('matchSelector').first();
```

Comment: The second one only requires a small change to the existing code, which I'm modifying. Thanks.