# Get next and only class on click in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the next class to show up when clicking on a more-infos span.

```
          <span>Total Current Liabilities</span> <span class="more-infos">click</span>
          <input type="text" name="currentratio2"  placeholder="$"></input>
          <p class="more-infos-container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum eligendi hic minus dicta atque molestiae, qui suscipit </p>
          <span>Total Current Assets</span> <span class="more-infos">click</span>
          <input type="text" name="currentratio1"  placeholder="$"></input>      
          <p class="more-infos-container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum eligendi hic minus dicta atque molestiae, qui suscipit </p>
```

Ideally, when you click on a more-infos link it will show up the more-infos-container that is the closest to itself. How is that achievable ?

I tried using next and find and closest but it doesn't work.

Thank you .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient, concise way to find next matching sibling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933236/efficient-concise-way-to-find-next-matching-sibling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/) method:

```js
$(function () {
    $('.more-infos').on('click', function (e) {
        var $info = $(this).nextAll('.more-infos-container').eq(0);
        alert($info.html());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Total Current Liabilities</span> <span class="more-infos">click</span>
<input type="text" name="currentratio2"  placeholder="$"></input>
<p class="more-infos-container">Liabilities Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum eligendi hic minus dicta atque molestiae, qui suscipit </p>

<span>Total Current Assets</span> <span class="more-infos">click</span>
<input type="text" name="currentratio1"  placeholder="$"></input>      
<p class="more-infos-container">Assets Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum eligendi hic minus dicta atque molestiae, qui suscipit </p>
```