# Target next instance of an element/div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following `HTML` structure and `JavaScript` file:

**.html**

```
<li>
 <button class="show-more"></button>
 some more elements
 <div class="hidden"></div>
</li>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$( ".show-more" ).click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $( this ).next().slideToggle( "fast", function() {
  });
});
```

I need the click event to toggle the next first instance of `.hidden`, however the click event is targeting the first element after it and not the next instance of `.hidden`, any ideas how I can go about it?

Comment: Note: you have to pass `event` as a parameter to callback-function of `.click` in order to use `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Note @empiric's very good catch there: As it is, your code is relying on a *global* `event` object, and relying on it having the `preventDefault` method. It will work on modern IE and Chrome, but will fail on Firefox (doesn't have a global `event`) and older IE (does, but that event doesn't have `preventDefault`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) and [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first):

```
$(this).nextAll('.hidden').first().slideToggle(...);
```

This question has more about this: [*Efficient, concise way to find next matching sibling?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4933236/157247)

Comment: @ShaunakD: that will only work when `.hidden` is immediate next sibling.

Comment: @ShaunakD: No, `next` doesn't scan, so `.next('.hidden')` will either give you the next element (if it has that class) or an empty set (if it doesn't).

Comment: Oh yes! Just checked that.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
$('~.hidden:first', this).slideToggle("fast");
```

This will match for the first, next sibling of the class `.hidden` in the context of `this`.
The `~`-selector will reach all following siblings.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ek0dxbkv/)**

**Reference**

[Next sibling selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)

[first selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

[context of selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context)