# use .prev() to set current element css

Tags: jquery, css

I've got pre-created HTML which I cannot edit.

What I am trying to do is get the color of all the `bar-appointment` to be the same as the previous `bar-something` background-color

I've got the following HTML

```
<div class="bar-something"><div class="fn-label"> SOMETHING</div> </div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap1</div></div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap2</div></div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap3</div></div>
<div class="bar-something-else"><div class="fn-label"> SOMETHING</div></div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap1</div></div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap2</div></div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap3</div></div>
```

And jquery

```
$('.bar-appointment .fn-label').css('color',$('.bar-appointment').prev().children().css('background-color'))
```

It's not fully working as it only picks the first `bar-something` and applies it to the rest. Please see the following [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2ttkea5h/)

Comment: Side note: `.prev()` will only include the immediate sibling before the current element. It does not continue searching if that sibling does not match the selector. [Efficient, concise way to find next matching sibling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933236/efficient-concise-way-to-find-next-matching-sibling)

Comment: I am not sure if it is a typo but you are trying to set the text color ??

Comment: @joyBlanks I am setting the text color

Comment: then why not `$('.bar-appointment .fn-label').css('color',$('.bar-something .fn-label').css('background-color'))`

Comment: @joyBlanks because the class `bar-something` is always different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('.bar-appointment').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.fn-label').css('color', $(this).prevAll(':not(.bar-appointment)').first().find('.fn-label').css('background-color'))
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ttkea5h/4/)