# How to get next text node with cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

```html
<p>
<i class="icon-home"></i>
address
<br>
<i class="icon-website"></i>
http://www.website.com
<br>
<i class="icon-tel"></i>
phone number
<br>
<i class="icon-mail"></i>
<a href="mailto:email@mail.com">Contact email</a>
<br>
</p>
```

I'm trying to get "address", "http://www.website.com" and "phone number".

```js
const address = $("i.icon-home").next();
const website = $("i.icon-website").next();
const phoneNumber = $("i.icon-tel").next();
```

Using `next()` gives me the next `<br>` element. How can I get the next text element?

Comment: What about `.next('i')`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - That wouldn't give them anything, because the next element is a `br`, not an `i`. They want the content of the text node following the `i` element.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right, so it acts like `+` in CSS, not `~`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Right. If the text were in a following element, you'd need `.nextAll("tagName").first()` to get the next matching one ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933236/efficient-concise-way-to-find-next-matching-sibling?r=SearchResults&s=1|26.4787)). But in this case, since it's a Text node, not an Element, we can't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The various jQuery-ish methods of Cheerio focus on Element nodes, but you're looking for the content of Text nodes.

The easiest way given the HTML you've shown is to use the underlying DOM(like) element's `nextSibling` to access its next sibling (which will be the Text node) and get the text from that via `nodeValue`:

```
const address = $("i.icon-home")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue;
const website = $("i.icon-website")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue;
const phoneNumber = $("i.icon-tel")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue;
```

(`[0]` accesses the first matching DOM(ish) element inside the Cheerio collection.)

A couple of notes on that:

1. You may want to trim whitespace off (by calling `trim()`), as the whitespace at the beginning and end of the Text nodes is preserved.
2. If you're unsure whether there will be a Text node (or indeed any node) following the image, you might want to be more defensive:

```
const getNextText = (element) => {
    if (!element.nodeName) { // If it's a Cheerio object...
        element = element[0];
    }
    const next = element.nextSibling;
    return next?.nodeType === 3 ? next.nodeValue.trim() : "";
};
```

Then

```
const address = getNextText($("i.icon-home"));
const website = getNextText($("i.icon-website"));
const phoneNumber = getNextText($("i.icon-tel"));
```